# How to change all non-null values in a column to the column name in SQL?

Tags: sql, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So let's say we have the following:

```
ID   data1  data2  data3
001   carl   NULL   NULL
002   NULL   rick   NULL
003   NULL  mitch   NULL
004   NULL   NULL   NULL
```

All I want to do is make every non-null value in the column name. Something like this in Snowflake.

```
ID   data1  data2  data3
001  data1   NULL   NULL
002   NULL  data2   NULL
003   NULL  data2   NULL
004   NULL   NULL   NULL
```

I have distinct rows as ID as well as a few columns I dont want this applied to. Any ideas how do tackle this in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id,
   case when data1 is not null then 'data1' else null end as data1,
...
```